# Transparent control graphics disappears over Unity3D player panel

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, transparent, graphics2d

I am stuck on a problem and all my google searches could not help me. My scenario is as follows

1) I have a panel and I load Unity3D player in there (works)

2) Then I have a transparent control with a panel and that overlays the first one (works)

3) Then I draw on the transparent panel using the mouseMove event (works)

4) Now, as soon as I load the unity content into the panel, the drawing (graphics) disappear.

To make sure it works, I move the drawing panel only halfway over the Unity panel and still, as soon as the Unity loads, only the drawings over the Unity panel disappear.

Please see image attached to explain it a bit more: [Transparent Panel Drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtWo1.jpg)

So I am not sure what should I google for in Winforms, since I am actually a Unity3d developer.

Comment: sorry, have to bump this question...